# Moving a subsite between site collections

Tags: site-collection, site

My users have created a sub site. They have done some work to it. They have now decided that it should site in the deparment it was created but another one as they will be looking after the site going forward. IS it possible to move asub site between site collections.

I know the URL will change (this is good) and that some links may need to be updated. I imagine permissions will also break so I would need to inherit from the new root site of the site collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be moved.

If you're on 2010 it can be done with [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx).  If you're on 2007, you can use stsadm [export](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262759.aspx) and [import](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261866%28v=office.12%29.aspx) operations to export the site to a file, then import it as a subsite to the desired location.