# Moving a sub site between Site Collections in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, site-collection, sub-site, team-sites

I have created a Site Collection and with a sub site for a department in our company.
Now they have requested to move that sub site to another site collection which belongs to another department.
How can i move the Sub Site from one site collection to the other site collection.

I am using SharePoint Online 2013 and both the sites are Team Sites.

I know this question is answered for SharePoint 2007 and 2010 platforms [in this question.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34020/moving-a-subsite-between-site-collections)
But i want to do it in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/sharepoint-online-move-site-and-subsites-into-another-site

Answer (score -1):

Use [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx) and  [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff607613(v=office.15).aspx) to achieve same result as with stsadm

Comment: How can i use power shell commands in SharePoint Online?
Please guide me through.I am new to SharePoint.

Comment: Sorry, actually I was wrong about these commands? You cannot use them in SharePoint online. The only solution I can advise to you - save site as template, then from solution gallery save to you disk as file, import this solution to another site collection's solution gallery, and recreate site form this new template.